# How to mock or stub chmod method under FileUtils class in ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, fileutils

Hi guys I really need help on how to stub or mock a **chmod** method under FileUtils class in ruby.

Currently I have this code.

```
def create_file(file)
    unless File.exist?(file)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(file), :mode => 0755)
        FileUtils.touch file
        FileUtils.chmod(0644, file)
    end
end
```

where **file** located under **/usr/local/something_folder/filePath.fileExtension**

And this is the equivalent test code I've created for that code above.

```
File.stub(:dirname).and_return('fileFullPath')
FileUtils.stub(:mkdir_p).and_return('fileFullPath')
FileUtils.stub(:touch).and_return('fileFullPath')
FileUtils.stub(:chmod).and_return('fileFullPath')
```

The problem here is the permission under **/usr/local** file path that's why I'm going to stub or mock that method call.

I would be glad and thankful if you can help me with this problem.

Happy coding guys :)

Comment: You might want to use https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One rule for mocking you have to consider is "mock only what you own". File and FileUtils you don't own. If you realy want to do it you can try gem `fakefs`. I would recommend another approch:

```
class YourClass
   attr_accessor :file_class, :file_utils_class

   def file_class
      @file_class ||= File
   end

   def file_utils_class
     @file_utils_class ||= FileUtils
   end

   def create_file(file)
     unless file_class.exist?(file)
       file_utils_class.mkdir_p(file_class.dirname(file), :mode => 0755)
       file_utils_class.touch file
       file_utils_class.chmod(0644, file)
     end
   end
 end
```

This way you can inject an object during test that behaves like you want.

Comment: "mocking what you own" is not always possible. Why should I let a vendor library (or standard library) for that matter do a long process instead of just mocking its return value for faster spec result?

Comment: Your code should call this method at least once , in a test, or you will not see  when this method changes it's behavior. Further more you can reconsider your design and decouple your code from such vendor libraries. When you mock this method directly you have a lot of assumptions in mind.